# How to pass arguments to a test function in laravel throw console

Tags: laravel, testing, tdd, laravel-artisan

I'm playing around with test in Laravel, and I want to test the same function with different users I've created. Is there a way to pass the id as an argument throw laravel console? I mean, writing something like:

```
 /** @test */
public function my_test_function($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
   ..........................}
```

And then calling with:

```
php artisan test --filter my_test_function ....... plus something to pass the id.
```

Answer (score 1):

The cli arguments are accesible in the global namespace. You can retrieve and dump them with something like:

```
/** @test */
public function my_test()
{
   global $argv;
   var_dump($argv);
   $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

However, phpunit shouldn't allow for arbitrary parameters

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -u 1
  PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

  Unknown option "-u"
```

You can resort to piggyback on a harmless option. For example, if you mean to pass an integer to match the user_id (as you probably do), you could probably do

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit --exclude-group 14
```

As long as you don't have a real test group called '14', and have the dump display:

```
  array (3) [
    0 => string (15) "vendor/bin/pest"
    1 => string (15) "--exclude-group"
    2 => string (2) "14"
  ]
```

You don't need to write your own parsing rules to handle those arguments, but it's still -as I said- piggybacking and it could break in several ways.  Before going further with that approach, I'd reccomend using  an environment variable defined right before the executable

```
       $ APP_USER_ID=14 vendor/bin/phpunit
```

which you can retrieve with

```
/** @test */
public function my_test()
{
   var_dump(getenv('APP_USER_ID'));
   $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

the dump will display the value you're looking for without involving arguments parsing

```
string (2) "14"
```